# Angular - How to bind only specific items in a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am currently using angular to build an application that uses buttons within Datatables to manipulate data. The current buttons I have available are "View" "Mark as completed", "Mark as incomplete", which upon clicking trigger specific functions. The relevant functionality is being achieved by the following:

```
/**
  * Hides ID and adds onclick functionality
  */
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const table = $('.display').DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      bRetrieve: true
    });
    table.column(0).visible(false);
    this.clickListener(table, this.route);
  }


  /**
  * Listens to row click
  */
  clickListener(table: any, route: any) {
    const self = this;
    let rowData;

    $('.display').on('click', 'tbody tr td .view', function(e) {
      rowData = self.checkIfRowsHidden(table, this, e);
      self.router.navigate([route + '/detail/' + rowData[0]]);
    });

    $('.display').on('click', 'tbody tr td .done', function(e) {
      rowData = self.checkIfRowsHidden(table, this, e);
      self.executePutData(rowData[0], 'Completed', self);
    });

    $('.display').on('click', 'tbody tr td .undone', function(e) {
      rowData = self.checkIfRowsHidden(table, this, e);
      self.executePutData(rowData[0], 'In Progress', self);
    });
  }
```

As you can see I am using `var self = this` in order to create a reference to the global scope. Please also note I am also using `this` within the function `checkIfRowsHidden` to capture the local scope. The function uses the local scope like this:

```
  checkIfRowsHidden(table, scope, event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (table.responsive.hasHidden()) {
      const parentRow = $(scope).closest("tr").prev()[0];
      return table.row( parentRow ).data();
    } else {
      return table.row($(scope).closest('tr')).data();
    }
  }
```

I recently introduced myself to using binding instead of `self` as a more structured and possibly memory efficient way. I tried to use it in my `clickListener` function by modifying it to the following:

```
  clickListener(table: any, route: any) {
    let rowData;

    $('.display').on('click', 'tbody tr td .view', function(e) {
      rowData = this.checkIfRowsHidden(table, this, e);
      this.router.navigate([route + '/detail/' + rowData[0]]);
    }.bind(this));
    /*rest of the code
    .
    .
    */
```

Unfortunately, since I had been using multiple scopes, the `this` from the local and global scopes were being treated as the same, creating errors while retrieving data from the tables. Is there a way to bind global scope to only a specific items? or do I have to resort to `var self=this`?

Comment: It's probably getting downvoted because of the mix of JQuery and Angular. It is usually frowned upon. Try to use Angular `Renderer2` and `ElementRef`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has bad coding conventions which is unacceptable in the community

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions to preserve global scope. Instead of using anonymous functions, you can switch to arrow functions, they automatically provide that:

```js
$('.display').on('click', 'tbody tr td .view', (e) => {
   rowData = self.checkIfRowsHidden(table, this, e);
   self.router.navigate([route + '/detail/' + rowData[0]]);
});
```

This way, you don't need to `bind` the scope, instead `this` refers to the Angular component class.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause both my local and global scopes to be treated as the same? Isn't there a way where I would preserve both scopes without the need for `self`?